# Do I need to set postfix myhostname and etc when virtual_mailbox_domains used?

Tags: postfix

I have configured postfix to use virtual mailboxes, it reads "virtual_mailbox_domains" for my virtual domains (I have only one domain). But I have run into confusion - what should I do with variables

```
mydestination, mydomain, myhostname, myorigin
```

Didn't find any HowTo that clarify this. I saw different variations - some of this variables empty, some set to one of virtual domains, some are localhost, some is set to "domain.not.used.for.virtual.domains.com, localhost"
Can I set all this variables to just "localhost" when using virtual mail domains?

Answer (score 2):

They should be configured to whatever is appropriate for your situation.  There is no one correct answer.

- `mydestination` -- what domains *do* you want to be delivered via the `$local_transport` mail delivery transport?  Even in a setup which uses virtual mailboxes, there are often domains you still want to be handled by the `local` transport.
- `mydomain` -- what *is* the internet domain name of this mail system?
- `myhostname` -- What *is* the internet hostname of this mail system?
- `myorigin` -- What domain *do* you want locally-posted mail to to appear to come from?

(If those questions sound familiar, it's because they're lightly modified variants of what's in `postconf`(5)).

Comment: An example of mails to be delivered locally, are mails sent locally, e.g. mails to root, sent by cron or logcheck etc. Also mails to postmaster should be directed to an appropriate mailbox, usually they are delivered to the host itself, not the domain.